# python import from symbolic linked script

Tags: python, django, linux

I have python script which inport module from directly below itself.

```
settings  --|-- base.py
manage.py   |-- init.py
```

Normally for this case . I can import `settings.base`.

However in my case `manage.py` is symbolic link.

```
settings  ------------------------------------------|-- base.py
manage.py -> /var/www/html/myapp/shared/manage.py   |-- init.py
```

I exec `manage.py` in the same directly.
but It shows the error No module named 'settings.base'

Is it impossible to use symbolic for this case??

Or is there any workaround??

Comment: does it still fail if you `import sys` and do `sys.path.append('/var/www/html/myapp/shared/')` ?

Comment: I added `sys.path.append(dir to manage.py)` it works!! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Append sys.path with the path to your symlinked package